# Why is my SAML Service Provider always making me authenticate?

Tags: saml

Our SAML-based SP, a SaaS, always requires authentication when we navigate to it, i.e., regardless of the fact that we've authenticated, if we open a new tab and navigate to it, our IdP is asking us to sign in again.

If we go directly to our IdP, sign in, and then open a new tab and navigate directly to the IdP again, it remembers and we don't have to authenticate again. In other words, it works as expected.

It's very strange and I've no idea why we're seeing this behavior. Granted, I don't understand how the IdP "knows" where the request is coming from so that it knows you've already authenticated, but clearly something's different even though it's the same SaaS that's making the request.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reason could be that "forceAuthn=true" is set in the SAML Authentication request.

This forces authentication every time.